# How can I trick Spark (using Yarn) to use all the nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, bigdata

Spark's execution of tasks seems to be memory centric if it uses the Yarn scheduler. If it see that the memory of the tasks could fit into less nodes,it won't bother running those tasks using all available nodes. Is there a way, I can ask Yarn to use all the nodes, without tricking it by increasing the memory of executors/containers?

Comment: Have you tried passing in `spark-submit` arg `--num-executors n` where n being number of nodes you want your application to use

Answer (score 1):

One of factors that could lead to more distribution of work is "    mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize". If you want more tasks (one executor has multiple tasks), then decrease this. You may have to strike a balance based on whether your task needs (memory/cpu/disk).

The above factor would work only if your input files are splittable. Examples of splittable files are uncompressed text (csv/tsv), compressed/uncompressed sequence, compressed/uncompressed orc/rc/parquet files.

Moreover, you may want to consider [spark dynamic allocation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)